# Aquatic Prime on 10.6 64bit not Compiling

Tags: aquaticprime

I need help with Aquatic Prime to get it run on 10.6.2 and 64bit.

```
ld: warning: in /AquaticPrime.framework/AquaticPrime, missing required architecture x86_64 in file
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AquaticPrime", referenced from:
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need the framework to have AquaticPrime license verification in your app.  Just include `AquaticPrime.c` and `AquaticPrime.h` files (the CoreFoundation version) in your source tree and you're good to go.  Furthermore using the plain C version is regarded as a more "secure" way of using AquaticPrime rather than the Objective-C version (citation needed ^_^).

That said, [my fork of AquaticPrime](http://github.com/adib/AquaticPrime) has some small modifications to reduce the warnings while compiling for 64-bit.

Thanks